# Redirect automatically from one component to another one after few seconds - react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I try to redirect the user from one component to another after a few seconds.

The user lands on a page and after few second he is automatically redirect to another page.
I thought to redirect in an action but I am not sure if it is the best idea (if you have easier way to do it I am interested).

My code so far:

a basic component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { redirectToProfile } from "../../actions/searchActions";

class Search extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.props.redirectToProfile(this.props.history), 3000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>search page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { redirectToProfile }
)(withRouter(Search));
```

and the action:

```
export const redirectToProfile = history => {
  history.push("/");
};
```

So far I have an error message:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

After some research I see that some people resolve the problem with the middleware thunk but I am already using it so I don't know what to do.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use the `<Redirect/>` component that `react-router` provides? I think that's clearer and more in keeping with React's declarative model, rather than hiding away the logic in an imperative thunk/action.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.id = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }), 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.id)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.redirect
      ? <Redirect to="/bar" />
      : <div>Content</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jed, indeed it is much clearer this way and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
state = {
    redirect: false // add a redirect flag
};

componentDidMount() {
    // only change the redirect flag after 5 seconds if user is not logged in
    if (!auth) {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }), 5000);
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // clear the timeer just in case
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

render() {
    // this is the key:
    // 1. when this is first invoked, redirect flag isn't set to true until 5 seconds later
    // 2. so it will step into the first else block
    // 3. display content based on auth status, NOT based on redirect flag
    // 4. 5 seconds later, redirect flag is set to true, this is invoked again
    // 5. this time, it will get into the redirect block to go to the sign in page
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
    } else {
        if (!auth) {
            return (
                <div className="center">
                    <h5>You need to login first to register a course</h5>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <div>Registration Page</div>;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using redux thunk and it's included in your project, you can create the action as following.

```js
export const redirectToProfile = history => {
  return (dispatch, setState) => {
    history.push('/');
  }
};

// shorter like this.
export const redirectToProfile = history => () => {
  history.push('/');
}

// and even shorter...
export const redirectToProfile = history => () => history.push('/');
```

**Alternative:**
You can also call `history.push('/');` right in the component if you adjust you default export of the Search component. This is preferred as you don't have overhead of creating an additional action and dispatching it through redux.

Change your export to...

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Search));
```

Then in your component use it as following...

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(this.props.history.push('/'), 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The redirection works I don't have the error message anymore.
But the setTimeout function doesn't work and I don't understand why.
Should I use it directly in the action or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is an example with functional commponent.

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Splash() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [time, setTime] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setTime(true)
        }, 2000)  
        setTime(false);
    }, []);
    return time ? navigate('/dashboard') : navigate('/account');
}
export default Splash;
```